# Problem with redefining Tabular environment with the \renewenvironment ‎command‎

Tags: macros, tables, environments

In a book I'm typesetting, I want the tabular environment to be in footnote size and the other body of the book to be in normalsize font. To do this, I've tried something like the following:

```
‎‎‎‎‎‎‎\re‎newenvironment‎{‎‎tabular‎‎}[1][t‎]{\footnotesize‎‎‎‎‎
\begin{tabular}‎
‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎[#1]}{‎‎‎‎\end{tabular}‎\normalsize‎‎‎‎}‎
```

But I get the following error:

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [save size=50000]. 
 <to be read again> 
               \relax 
 l.72 \centering\begin{tabular}{
                           cccccc}
```

By the way, I'm using the tabular as below:

```
\begin{‎table}[t]‎
\caption{Title}\label{tab1‎}‎‎
‎\centering‎‎‎‎‎\begin{‎tabular}{c‎c‎‎‎‎‎‎c‎‎c‎‎‎‎cc‎‎}‎‎‎
‎....
‎‎‎\end{‎tabular}‎
\end{‎table}‎‎
```

Have I done something wrong here?

### Edit on December 28th (another question):

In the following code,  if I want also to add a `\centering` command, where should I put it? I have put it before and after the `\footnotesize` but it doesn't work!

```
\let\oldtabular\tabular
\let\endoldtabular\endtabular
\renewenvironment{tabular}{\bgroup\footnotesize\oldtabular}%
                          {\endoldtabular\egroup}
```

Comment: Could you please add the error messages to the question?

Comment: Don't do such adjustments: you'll be sorry when you'll need a plain `tabular` environment. The `\centering` and `\footnotesize` commands belong to the `table` environment and *not* to `tabular`. Use a new environment, if you prefer.

Comment: Please don't use edits to ask a follow-up question; instead, ask a new question and provide a link to the original question for the context.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A better approach is to define a new tabular environment with your own customizations

```
\newenvironment{smalltabular}{\footnotesize\tabular}{\endtabular}
```

And then use `smalltabular` instead of `tabular`. A few things to note:

- In the definition of a new environment, instead of `\begin{tabular}` and `\end{tabular}` it's enough to say `\tabular` and `\endtabular`.
- You don't need to register any arguments for `smalltabular`, because the last command in it's definition (i.e. `\tabular`) will already look for and process any arguments appropriately.

If for some reason you *really* want to redefine the tabular environment, you first need to save its old definition and then redefine it. For example:

```
\let\oldtabular\tabular
\let\endoldtabular\endtabular
\renewenvironment{tabular}{\footnotesize\oldtabular}{\endoldtabular}
```

Comment: Thanks Juan, your reply is completely understandable.
Thanks everybody.

Comment: Your method for redefining the tabular environment is cleaner than my suggestion. As for "some reason" to redefine: I like to implement general changes (changing the fontsize for tabular) in the preamble rather than to replace every "tabular" with "smalltabular" in the document body.

Comment: The `\bgroup` and `\egroup` are redundant, as *any* environment forms a group by itself.

Comment: Thanks for noting that. I've just edited the answer accordingly

Comment: And `\usepackage{etoolbox}` followed by `\preto\tabular{\footnotesize}` is even easier. :)

Comment: @Glorfindel Bumping old old questions by editing them to fix a couple of typos is a little unnecessary. Indeed, it's [advised against](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340/when-is-and-isnt-it-acceptable-to-edit?rq=1)

Comment: @Seamus OK, thanks. Generally on Stack Exchange it's an accepted practice, but if it's different here, so be it.

Answer (score 4):

Using the `\tabular` macro inside a redefinition of the same macro will produce an infinite loop. Try the following:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\tabular}{\let\@halignto\@empty\footnotesize\@tabular}
\makeatother
```

Comment: What a interesting method! can u please explain more about that? what is the role of @halignto and @empty?

Comment: I don't know their roles. ;-) I simply looked up the original definition of `\tabular` in the `article` class (using `\show\tabular`), added `\footnotesize` in a location that seemed plausible and tested the resulting code.

Answer (score 3):

When you use \renewenvironment, it doesn't expand the new definition until it is used. So in your case, when you call it, it tries to expand the new tabular environment and substitutes the \begin{tabular}, you've included in that one, leading to another one, and so on, leading to an infinite loop.

In general you cannot define an environment or command in terms of itself, unless you're very very careful to ensure that's its recursively well-grounded.

(EDIT: Sorry to duplicate lockstep; we were answering at the same time.)

Comment: Thanks for your complete reply. What do you mean exactly by "unless you're very very careful to ensure that's its recursively well-grounded."?