# Lyx drop-in table replacement to allow table footnotes

Tags: tables, lyx

I want to be able to use footnotes in LyX while preserving the LyX table structure. Any way to force LyX to use a different environment for its built-in tables that allows that? I.e. some code to put in the preamble.

[This page](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables#Footnotes_in_tables) recommended `longtabular` (couldn't find it anywhere) or `tabu`.

Edit: I tried to use the approach in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2590/problem-with-redefining-tabular-environment-with-the-renewenvironment-command) to replace `tabular` with `tabu`, but it seems to get `pdftex` stuck in an infinite loop.

```
% Replace tabular with tabu.
\let\oldtabular\tabular
\let\endoldtabular\endtabular
\renewenvironment{tabular}{\tabu}{\endtabu}
```

Edit 2: As it has been indicated that tabu is unreliable/unmaintained, any other environment you would recommend for this purpose?

Comment: avoid tabu. See: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/comp.text.tex/Bug$20in$20tabu$20with$20scantokens/comp.text.tex/xRGJTC74uCI/anwgH1lFGZkJ

Comment: The topic ID is invalid.

Comment: Try this one: https://groups.google.com:443/forum/?fromgroups=#!topicsearchin/comp.text.tex/tabu/comp.text.tex/xRGJTC74uCI

Comment: You can try the package ftnxtra: http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ftnxtra

Comment: Or you use `threeparttable`: http://www.ctan.org/pkg/threeparttable

Comment: ftnextra seems to give me an error about missing # in the tabular's alignment preamble :(

Comment: `threeparttable` works, but is not a drop-in replacement so I have to write a lot of ERT around the table.

Comment: @Dan Have you tried my answer below, which is purely using LyX?

Answer (score 2):

Let me provide a small answer

**Avoid the packag `tabu`**

The current version of tabu is *2.8 release*. However the author wants to upload a new version whereby most of the current commands will be invalid.

The author wrote at comp.text.tex: [Bug in tabu with scantokens (GL, please fix)](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topicsearchin/comp.text.tex/tabu/comp.text.tex/xRGJTC74uCI)

> Well, to be honest, the time of bug reports will come with the next 
>   release. I'm just implementing the \multirow feature, and I have to 
>   say that the current available code is very far from what i'm working 
>   on now.

That means the current version is completely unmaintained.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't initially aware. I changed my question to what I'm actually interested in, how to make footnotes work automatically in LyX tables.

Answer (score 2):

Please try to avoid `tabu`.  As stated by jon [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45479/longtable-in-footnote-leads-to-overfull-page/106427#106427):

> I would recommend staying away from tabu as the package author is
>   still fiddling with things and explicitly promised that there would
>   not be backwards compatibility. See [here](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.text.tex/browse_thread/thread/c511894c2ef8b822/df91b50e43a35c86?lnk=gst&q=tabu#df91b50e43a35c86) for the discussion.

If you are trying to get the 'X' funcionality of `tabularx` with the breakable option of `longtable`, Alan Munn recommends using the `ltxtable` package ([link](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/carlisle/) to CTAN), written by David Carlisle (see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/106452/27833)).

Other thing you can do is still use `tabularx`, put it inside a `table` environment and reduce its size.  You can always rotate it 90 degrees to get a more space.

For more information about table packages, please refer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12673/27833)

Comment: Thanks! Does `ltxtable` support table footnotes out of the box?

Comment: Give it a try :).  Most likely @David Carlisle thought about it

Comment: Did the answer work?

Answer (score 0):

Right click into the table and select "More > Settings...". (Alternatively, move the cursor into the table and open the menu "Edit > Table settings...".) Go to tab "Longtable" and make a tick at "Use long table"!

(This way the built-in "LyX table editor" is still used, and the `tabular` environment is replaced by the `longtable` environment.)