# Ignore \extrarowheight for \cases

Tags: tables, spacing

I'm using `\extrarowheight` (in combination with `booktabs`) to make the tables in my thesis more readable. However, this also affects the layout of the `cases` environment, which now look strange; in the following example, the `X` is placed too far down now.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\setlength{\extrarowheight}{4pt}
\setlength{\belowrulesep}{0pt}

\begin{document}
    \[
    a = \begin{cases}
            X \\
            Y
        \end{cases}
    \]

    \begin{tabular}{llll}\toprule
    $a^b$ & $a_b$ & $a$ & $b$ \\ \midrule
    a & b & c & d \\
    \bottomrule 
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is there any way to ignore the `\extrarowheight` in the `cases` environment?

I guess there is some `\renewcommand` magic that can do this, but I'm not if that's the right way to go, let alone where I would start... I also realize that I could reset `\extrarowheight` to `0` before the `\cases` and set it again afterwards, but my DRY alarm tells me not to `;)`.

Comment: One approach would be to renew the tabular environment and set the large extrarowheight so it was confined to that environment only.

Comment: Without seeing one of your tables it's hard to guess though.

Comment: @Thruston See the updated question with an example of a table.

Comment: Redefinition would be tricky since `cases` uses `array`. However you can consider using `mathtools`' `cases*` which does not rely on `array`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an answer with a redefined `tabular`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newenvironment{airytabular}{\setlength{\extrarowheight}{4pt}\setlength{\belowrulesep}{0pt}%
  \begin{tabular}}{\end{tabular}}
\begin{document}
\[
a = \begin{cases}
        X \\
        Y
    \end{cases}
\]

\begin{airytabular}{llll}\toprule
$a^b$ & $a_b$ & $a$ & $b$ \\ \midrule
a & b & c & d \\
\bottomrule 
\end{airytabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Setting up a new environment like this is in general the best approach, because other packages, and indeed the standard class files may use `tabular` expecting the normal behaviour.  However if you *really* want to redefine it, you can, but you have to capture the previous behaviour to avoid a regression into a loop.  Here's one way to do that.

```
\let\ltxtab\tabular
\let\ltxendtab\endtabular
\renewenvironment{tabular}{\setlength{\extrarowheight}{4pt}\setlength{\belowrulesep}{0pt}%
\ltxtab}{\ltxendtab}
```

With this re-definition, your `tabular` environments will have the changed space, but nothing else will be affected, as you desired.

This question has come up [before](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2590/problem-with-redefining-tabular-environment-with-the-renewenvironment-command) by the way.

Comment: Thanks, that looks good! Just one nit-pick: is it possible to redefine `tabular` so that I don't have to go through the whole document and replace all occurrences?

Comment: Yes... but that's slightly trickier as you have to be careful not to get into a loop.  On the whole, I'd recommend using a different name, in case you want to use the normal tabular some where.  Does your editor not do global find and replace ? :-)

Comment: That's the point, to make sure the layout is consistent throughout the document I don't want to be able to use the normal tabular (at least not without additional effort) ;-).

So this is more interesting from an best-practices point of view than for the concrete problem, where search and replace will of course work perfectly well (`sed` FTW ;-) ).

Comment: OK, we can do that.  I've updated the answer to show you how.

Answer (score 5):

You can define `\extrarowheight` and `\belowrulesep` only inside the `tabular` environment using `etoolbox`. It provides a hook `\AtBeginEnvironment`. You have to add these lines in your preamble:

```
\AtBeginEnvironment{tabular}{%
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{4pt}
\setlength{\belowrulesep}{0pt}
}%
```

without anything more.

Full code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{tabular}{%
    \setlength{\extrarowheight}{4pt}
    \setlength{\belowrulesep}{0pt}
    }%

\begin{document}
    \[
    a = \begin{cases}
            X \\ 
            Y
        \end{cases}
    \]

    \begin{tabular}{llll}\toprule
    $a^b$ & $a_b$ & $a$ & $b$ \\ \midrule
    a & b & c & d \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Harish Kumar, that's a much better way with `etoolbox`.  Do you want me to edit these into a single answer?  Is there some way to accept yours rather than mine?

Comment: @Thruston I think they can stay as separate answers as they are totally different in approaches (it will improve readability). And regarding accepting, it is up to OP. It is OK to have your answer as accepted :-)

Comment: @HarishKumar just as an heads-up (because I just ran into it), you should comment the newlines in the `\AtBeginEnvironment`, otherwise there will be some spaces before the tabular.